# VBSscript regex replace text between curly

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I have looked at multiple expamples here and they all partially work but not all together.

I am trying to create a regex to replace text in a string based on an variable.  I get the replace to work, but only on the first search. etc.

The goal is to replace:  Text: {1} Text from user 1.
{2} Text from user 2.
{1} Text from user 1.
 - When if the QueryString.  I need to replace the text between the { }.

If QueryString = a user # for example 1 then show name, otherwise Show "User None":

Respone:  Text: NAME1 Text from user 1.
User None Text from user 2.
NAME1 Text from user 1.
 - When if the QueryString.

### -----------------------------------

---

OK - I had the file finally:

```
<%
Dim StrX, CallMe, varID, varFirmID, varBKID
CallMe = "0"
CallMe = Request.QueryString("x")
StrX = "Memo Tracking:<br />"
StrX =  StrX & "{1} Test Text 1<br/ >{2} Test Text 2<br/ >{1} Test Text 1<br/ >{2} Test   Text 2<br/ >" 'Data - will replace with Recordset Data later - eventually I will also add   [] for two sets
varFirmID = "0"
varBKID = "0"

Set re = new RegExp 
re.IgnoreCase = true
re.Global = true
re.Pattern = "\{(.*)\}" 'find {} part
set matches = re.Execute(StrX) 

'finds Matches of Firms --------------------------------
If matches.Count > 0 Then
For Each Match in Matches 
varFirmID = matches.item(0).submatches(0)
    If Callme = varFirmID Then
        StrX =(Replace(StrX,matches.item(0).submatches(0),"Replaced Name:"))
            End If
            If Callme <> varFirmID Then
        StrX =(Replace(StrX,matches.item(0).submatches(0),"NO NAME:"))
    End If
Response.Write Strx
'End loop if Match --------------------------------
Next
End If
%>
```

I keep getting partial results.  I have a feeling I need to add a "do while loop" after the for code.

The goal is... querystring(x)=1 results:

Memo Tracking:
Replaced Name1: Test Text 1
NO NAME: Test Text 2
Replaced Name1: Test Text 1
NO NAME: Test Text 2

The goal is... querystring(x)=2 results:

Memo Tracking:
NO NAME: Test Text 1
Replaced Name2: Test Text 2
NO NAME: Test Text 1
Replaced Name2: Test Text 2

(I will run a recordset in the loop using varFirmID as a key - so I will likely need a suggestion where to insert that.)
THANKS MUCH FOR ANY HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Add first glance, I see an error in your pattern: You use a forwardslash kind of 'start of pattern' as you could do in Javascript / Java but not in VBScript

```
re.Pattern = "/{(.*)}/"
```

should be:

```
re.Pattern = "{(.*)}"    ' note: is not going to work for you either, read below
```

but, the curly brackets are also special characters (repeat count of former sequence), so you have to escape them:

```
re.Pattern = "\{(.*)\}"
```

Another error I spotted in your code:

```
if matches > o then
```

you should replace the `o` with a `0` and `matches` with `matches.count`:

```
if matches.count > 0 then
```

OK, now we are getting somewhere. The code is working, but returns `1} Text from user 1.<br/>{2} Text from user 2.<br/>{1` instead of just the first number because the regex is [matching greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). Regular expression are fun, because you can create different solutions for the same problem. I choose for just getting the number part from the string, but you can also figure out other solutions:

```
re.Pattern = "\{(\d+)\}"
```

The plus (+) sign after the \d indicates that you want 1 to unlimited times a digit, so even if your number exceeds 9 it will work.

I hope I could clear that out. I did notice that this will not solve your problem because you want to replace something as it matches a certain condition. The fixed pattern will help you and maybe if you could clearify your question more and provide an example with an exact input/output we could help you further on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I really appreciate the assistance.  I added my updated code finally. If you get a chance to peek at it, I am grateful.

Comment: @OliverFleener The regex on your updated code looks better, but it is still matching greedy as explained in my answer. You need to replace the `.*` with `\d` to match a single number and not a whole messy string until the last `}`.

Comment: @OliverFleener Oh, and this one goes rogue: `varFirmID = matches.item(0).submatches(0)`. You can either do a `for each match in matches` and then take the match one by one using `foo = match.submatches(0)` (and submatches(1) etc), or you can use `for i = 0 to matches.count` and get this matches item with `foo = matches.item(i).submatches(0)`. Right now you are mixing them and that is giving you a wrong result.

Comment: AC- Thanks for the quick reply.  I tried both suggestions and what seems a 100 variations of each, but confess with obvious humility I am not good at this.  I can't get this thing to loop through, with a count etc.  I switched out the pattern string but it eats into some of the text too... [link]http://www.clwwest.com/csg/1test.asp you can see I stink at this an additional detail would be huge for me.  thanks in advance.